# Is "Incain" an old spelling of insane?

Tags: 19th-century, england, death-records, palaeography, cause-of-death

This [bishop's transcript](http://interactive.ancestry.com/2478/4420912_00569/55410487?backurl=&ssrc=pt_t62928579_p48097634308_kpgz0q3d32799_m1&backlabel=Return#?imageId=4420912_00569)  shows cause of death, which is quite illuminating especially the number that are just listed as ["decline"](http://www.rootschat.com/forum/index.php?topic=366971.0). The record at number 49, of William Towler, has cause of death listed as "Incain". Or at least that's what I think it says.

Could it mean "insane"? Or have I missed something?

Comment: I think this could be an interesting question to ask at http://English.stackexchange.com too.  If you decide to do that, and so that it does not get labelled and closed as a Cross Post, I would re-word it along the lines of "I found **Incain** written in an old document from 1746 where **Insane** may have been expected - is that an earlier accepted spelling or just an example of poor spelling?"  I would be curious to see the outcome recorded here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parish register version is also on Ancestry

(see 
Name:   William Towler
Birth Date:     abt 1746
Burial Date:    3 Apr 1804
Death Age:  58
Parish:     Colne, St Bartholomew, Lancashire, England
Register Type:  Parish Register
Reference Number:   PR 3172/1/47 )

The cause of death there clearly reads "**Insane**" - using that spelling. I have no idea how "Insane" turned into "Incain". I doubt I'm misreading the "s" as a "c". And in any case the rear 3 letters alter!

Comment: Thanks, I'm not quite sure how I missed the parish record itself.